# Is it possible, in WCF, to add a global message inspector?

Tags: wcf, global, behavior

There are a bunch of questions regarding global error handlers and such but none of those address what I need.

Is there any way to add a behavior that will attach to every endpoint or service through .config?

*Specifically what I want to do is add a logger that will capture and log every SOAP request/response. But I would prefer that behavior to be automatically added to every service I have instead of having to manually add it to each.

I looked into behavior extensions and thought that would be the solution but no, you have to add the behavior to every service.*

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to use the [`<commonBehaviors>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa734725.aspx) section of your **machine.config** file to define a behavior which would be applied to all services in your machine. Notice that updating the machine.config is really like using a bazooka to solve your problem (and in many scenarios the group policy may forbid you from doing that), so it may not work for all scenarios. You'll also need to make sure that the behavior extension is registered (also in machine.config), and that whatever application you're using with WCF has access to the assembly referenced in the extension (possibly via GAC).

Another alternative would be to use a common library for creating the service hosts (either directly for self-hosted services or via a service host factory for webhosted services), and use that library (which would in turn add the inspector).

Comment: Yeah, going the machine.config way seems to be overkill for this. I'll be looking into service host factories. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Its always good to have a message inspector to get rid of this kind of problem. Message Inspector is an implementation of WCF extension which works nicely to track every incoming request(s) and outgoing response(s) for your service, even if its fails in Message Validation it has an option to trap and work accordingly. More precisely the message inspector can configure using configuration files without making changes in your existing service.

More details about your Message inspector and its implementation can be found [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717047.aspx)

Hope this helps !!

Happy Coding :)